# Database connection lost whenever query string is too long

Tags: mysql, activerecord, mariadb

I recently switched from running [my Rails app](https://github.com/WikiEducationFoundation/WikiEduDashboard) on a single VM to running the database — MariaDB 10.3 — on a separate (Debian Buster) VM. Now that the database is on a separate server, Rails immediately throws `Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: MySQL server has gone away` whenever it tries to make a query where the SQL itself is very long. (They query itself isn't necessarily one that would put significant load on the system.)

An example query that causes the problem looks like this:

```
SELECT `articles`.`id` FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`namespace` = 0 AND `articles`.`wiki_id` = 1 AND `articles`.`title` IN ('Abortion', 'American_Civil_Liberties_Union', 'Auschwitz_concentration_camp', 'Agent_Orange', 'Ahimsa')
```

... except the array of titles is about 5000 items long, and the full query string is ~158kB.

On the database side, this corresponds to warnings like this:

`2021-03-25 15:47:13 10 [Warning] Aborted connection 10 to db: 'dashboard' user: 'outreachdashboard' host: 'programs-and-events-dashboard.globaleducation.eqiad1.wikimed' (Got an error reading communication packets)`

The problem seems to be with the network layer, but I can't get to the bottom of it. I've tried adjusting many MariaDB config variables (`max_allowed_packet`, `innodb_log_buffer_size`, `innodb_log_file_size`, `innodb_buffer_pool_size`) but none of those made a difference. The problem seems to be that the connection is aborted while it is attempting to transmit the long SQL query string from the app server to the database server. (There's no corresponding problem with receiving large query results from the database.)

Comment: try https://mariadb.com/kb/en/transaction-timeouts/

Comment: I've looked into that, but I don't believe it is related to any of the timeout settings. The `interactive_timeout` and `wait_timeout` settings are both long (28800) while I can replicate the error immediately upon issuing a query. An `Aborted connection` warning looks different if it's a timeout vs "error reading communication packets".

Comment: May be better to ask this question at: [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) Also, the information [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/16/mysql-got-an-error-reading-communication-packet-errors/) could be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after posting it to dba.stackexchange.com, I figured it out!

The problem was solved by upgrading libmariadb-dev on the Rails application server and rebuilding the `mysql2` gem.

Previously, the system was running on a single server with a mariadb-10.1 database. After the switch to a separate database server, the database was on mariadb-10.3 but it was still connecting from the same Rails environment as before, with a `mysql2` gem built against 10.1.